# How to open new Fragment when click on Expandablelist View item

Tags: android, expandablelistview

can any one solve my problem i wanna open new fragment when click on expandable list items and also come back to expandable list i wanna create fragment for each child item.

Main Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ExpandableFragment expandableFragment = new ExpandableFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container,expandableFragment).commit();
}}
```

activity xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.irfanattari.explistviewfragment.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and adapter class

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.listHashMap = listHashMap;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return listDataHeader.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1); //i=group item i1=child item
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(i);
        if (view == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);

        }
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        final String childText = (String)getChild(i,i1);
        if (view == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        }
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);

        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and code for expandable list fragment

```
public class ExpandableFragment extends Fragment{


private ExpandableListView listView;
private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<String> listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHash;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_fragment,container,false);

    listView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    initData();
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listHash);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


    return rootView;
}

private void initData() {

    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    listHash = new HashMap<>();

    listDataHeader.add("اراکین کابینہ");
    listDataHeader.add("ڈویژن نگران و مشاورت");
    listDataHeader.add("علاقائی نگران و مشاورت");
    listDataHeader.add("حلقہ نگران و مشاورت");
    listDataHeader.add("ذیلی نگران و مشاورت");

    List<String> ak = new ArrayList<String>();
    ak.add("اراکین کابینہ لسٹ");

    List<String> dnwm = new ArrayList<String>();
    dnwm.add("انوار مرشد");
    dnwm.add("گلزار مرشد");
    dnwm.add("قرار مرشد");
    dnwm.add("دیار مرشد");

    List<String> enwm = new ArrayList<String>();
    enwm.add("انوار مرشد");
    enwm.add("گلزار مرشد");
    enwm.add("قرار مرشد");
    enwm.add("دیار مرشد");

    List<String> hnwm = new ArrayList<String>();
    hnwm.add("انوار مرشد");
    hnwm.add("گلزار مرشد");
    hnwm.add("قرار مرشد");
    hnwm.add("دیار مرشد");

    List<String> znwm = new ArrayList<String>();
    znwm.add("انوار مرشد");
    znwm.add("گلزار مرشد");
    znwm.add("قرار مرشد");
    znwm.add("دیار مرشد");

    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(0),ak);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(1),dnwm);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(2),enwm);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(3),hnwm);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(4),znwm);

}}
```

and expandable fragment layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lvExp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:divider="#f00"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="#0f0"
    android:childDivider="#0f0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and ak fragment that is open when click on child item

```
public class AKFragment extends Fragment {


public AKFragment() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ak_fragment,container,false);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

and  its layout contain text view display

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
setOnChildClickListener(ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener onChildClickListener)

setOnGroupClickListener(ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener onGroupClickListener)
```

From the ExpandableListView

Comment: thanks. but my question was when click on item a new fragment open... i can not open fragment .... but after many try i finally opened fragment on item click

Comment: Can you share your solution @IrfanAhmed?